# How can I fix a bug when swipe stops to work when I swipe down till the end of the screen?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

So, I created a swipe using react native redash and reanimated. Here is my code:
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  timeContainer: {
    
  },

  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
  },

  display: {
    marginTop: height / 2,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

const TEXT_HEIGHT = styles.text.fontSize * 1.34;

const App = () => {
  const [containerHeight, setContainerHeight] = useState(height);

  const SampleFunction = (item) => {
    Alert.alert(item);
  }

  let numbers = new Array(41);

  for (let i = 0, num = 0; i < numbers.length; i++, num += 5) {
    numbers[i] = num;
  }

  const {
    gestureHandler,
    translation,
    velocity,
    state,
  } = usePanGestureHandler();

  const translateY = diffClamp(withDecay({ 
    value: translation.y, 
    velocity: velocity.y, 
    state, 
  }), 
    -numbers.length * TEXT_HEIGHT + containerHeight - height, 
    0
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.display}> 
      <PanGestureHandler 
        {...gestureHandler}
        onLayout={({
          nativeEvent: {
            layout: { height: h },
          },
        }) => setContainerHeight(h)}
      >
        <Animated.View style={styles.timeContainer}> 
          {numbers.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <Animated.View 
                key={index} 
                style={[
                  { transform: [{ translateY }] },
                ]}
              >
                <Text style={styles.text} onPress={SampleFunction.bind(item)}>{item}</Text>
              </Animated.View> 
            );
          })}
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </View>
  )
};

export default App;
```

So, when I swipe down till the very end of the screen, swipe just doesn't work. That bug appeared when I added style prop 'marginTop: height / 2'. I added it cause I want my array to start at the middle of the screen. How can I fix that?